# Tensorflow on Android with Python bindings?

Tags: python, tensorflow, kivy

I am trying to build Tensorflow core with Python bindings for Android - to be used from a Kivy app in Android, but not sure how to get the Python bindings working.

Compiling the Tensorflow core for Android works with the following:

```
bazel build -c opt \
  --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
  --cpu=armeabi-v7a \
  --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
  --verbose_failures \
  //tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib
```

Does anybody know how to add Python bindings to it? Is that even possible?

I have read the documentations, did lots of searching, but no luck finding anything about this. I saw that lot of other people are also interested in getting Tensorflow working on Kivy (both for Android and iOS), but nobody seems to have done it so far. People only got as far as saying that we would need an python-for-android recipe built, but the first step for a recipe is to build for Android with Python bindings, hence the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: I have never worked with Tensorflow*

---

Judging from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow) the only dependency problem here might be NumPy, but there's a [recipe for it](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/numpy). So, we have NumPy, *but* there's no recipe for the Tensorflow itself. What now?

The answer is in the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) on how to make a recipe.

First I'd look at the already working recipes, to actually understand how they work, especially the ones that work with C/C++ and **not with Cython** as it's a little bit easier to make a recipe for Cython (more even if you made the code).

These are the recipes I consider a basic stone for creating a recipe for Tensorflow:

- [Protobuf](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/protobuf_cpp/__init__.py)(C++)
- [OpenSSL](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/openssl/__init__.py)

Each of them has a part that will help you to assemble a working recipe. Now, there's a problem with the bindings. There are `manylinux` wheels, but those most likely won't help you on Android (like *at all*) in the state they are. Therefore you'll need to build from source (obviously) and they have [a whole folder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a86b86a2d25efbc5767ac5d270725bf85db183ff/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py) related to that part.

That leads us to your piece of `bazel` code. In [build_pip_package.sh](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a86b86a2d25efbc5767ac5d270725bf85db183ff/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.sh) there's a lot of lines related to the bazel thingy.

So, after you understand how the recipes work there are two possibilities:

- your piece of code actually does something and builds it for android
- your code is worthless

***If*** your code actually works, there's a good chance you'll be able to combine the already made `setup.py` file into a simple-looking recipe hopefully just with another platform check (and using the correct `bazel` binary I presume). As there already is `setup.py` file, the package files should be moved to the Python that's compiled for Android.

On the other hand if the piece of code you pasted above is worthless, then you'll probably end up with compiling the code yourself + reinventing their `setup.py` just for the P4A as a recipe. If you aren't familiar with the compilation steps required for building from source, I really don't envy you the process.

---

Also it might be a good thing to mention the ***size*** of the final APK. You can see Tensorflow on PyPI with just a small wheel of 13MB for Windows. Manylinux wheels, however, are *huge* (37-42MB) and I think you'll end up with a size inbetween those two for Android if you plan to install anything else than Tensorflow itself. There's always NumPy you'll have to drag with it to the phone as a dependency. So that gives you ~50MB+ APK file, which might not be really desired (depends on you).

[This piece of code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/util/python) related to Python in their repo might help you too.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions. Very thorough. Unfortunately my problem is getting the Tensorflow compiling for Android (see my compile code in the question) to include Python binding, so no setup.py getting generated. I was hoping that the Tensorflow guys will chip in here, as they suggest questions to be raised on Stackoverflow and they supposed to monitor those. In either case, thanks for the very detailed description of the general strategy for the Kivy recipe.